# How to ignore uninitialized variable error in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

I'm having problems with MSVS compiler, I have the following code:

```
if (!list) {
    *type = raw_data[*i++];
    ptr = (char*) &size;
    ptr[1] = raw_data[*i++];
    ptr[0] = raw_data[*i++];
    name = new char[size+1];
    memcpy (name, raw_data+*i, size);
    name[size] = '\0';
    *i += size;
}
```

And later:

```
if (!list) {
    s->name = name;
    s->name_size = size;
}
```

The value of list doesn't change in this function, however I can't compile the code because of this error:

> Error 1   error C4703: potentially uninitialized local pointer variable
>   'name' used

I find it incredibly annoying that this isn't a warning but an error. Changing the bool to const bool doesn't help either. Does someone know how to ignore this specific error in Visual Studio, but still show other errors/warnings?

Comment: How about adding an initialization for name, e.g., `char* name(0);`?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `std::string` ? I think you might know that the assignment operation in your case is a shallow copy.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj851030.aspx, it is a warning. You may use `#pragma warning (disable: 4703)` or better fix the code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect you're passing the compiler the `/sdl` option, which tells it to treat a 4703 (and various other things) as an error rather than a warning.

In the context of being paranoid about security it makes sense to treat this as an error - the compiler can't prove that what you're doing is safe, so it won't let the code through. If you don't want that, turn off `/sdl`.

Answer (score 10):

There is checkbox for `SDL checks` when you create new project (wizard) in visual Studio 2015. If this is enabled, Visual Studio will report uninitialized variables as warning as part of potential other things, more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161081.aspx).

If you already have a project with SDL checks on, you can disable it from project properties like in screen shot below. This way you don't have to deal with changing any command line arguments.

[image]